# How to print a file on MAXMSP

Tags: c++, file, max-msp-jitter

I have this part of code. I want to print the contents of the file ,but everything I tried didn't work. Could you please help?

```
void ofxGVF::loadTemplates(string filename){
//    clear();
//

ofxGVFGesture loadedGesture;
loadedGesture.clear();

ifstream infile;
stringstream doung;

infile.open (filename.c_str(), ifstream::in);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "print the contents"? Print it on the console? On a printer? Something else? What *have* you tried?

Comment: On unrelated note, when using `std::ifstream` the `in` mode is set by default when calling `open`, you don't have to provide it.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg, I want the contents of the file to be printed on the MAXMSP console when I run my project.